# One-liner to list collections in a MongoDB server

Tags: mongo-shell

I want a one-liner to list collections in a database like so

```
$ mongo
> ls <db_name>
(collections listed)
```

instead of lengthy and inconvenient

```
$ mongo
> use <db_name>
switched to db <db_name>
> show tables
(collections listed)
```

.

Trying to do it in one line fails, for example:

```
> use admin show tables
2022-01-01T20:34:09.707+0000 E  QUERY    [js] Error: [admin show tables] is not a valid database name :
Mongo.prototype.getDB@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:63:12
getDatabase@src/mongo/shell/session.js:927:28
DB.prototype.getSiblingDB@src/mongo/shell/db.js:22:12
shellHelper.use@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:803:10
shellHelper@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:790:15
@(shellhelp2):1:1
```

I would at least like to pack two things in one line, like:

`use <db_name>` `show tables`

Note: I'm asking more about communicating with the `DB Server` and managing connections in the background to retrieve information desired, rather than a particular connection to a particular `DB`.

Answer (score 1):

Look @ the error.

```
Error: [admin; show tables] is not a valid database name :
```

That's just a syntax issue.

Issue is the user \ database should be specified in the login itself

```
mongosh "mongodb://127.0.0.1" --username my_username --password my_password
    --authenticationDatabase my_database
```

You can then run commands with --eval "command" in the same one liner.  You should be selecting the DB in the oneliner, not trying to create a transaction of chained commands at this point.

Comment: I'd like the shell to implicitly connect to the database with name provided as parameter, and return the tables in it, when I type a simple one-liner. Perhaps I should rename the question -- "**one-liner to list collections in a database**, without switching permanently to that database.

Comment: One liner in shell?  Bash?  What is executing the code and what is connecting to the DB?

(ie do you want a 1 liner that you paste into Putty?  Do you want a one liner for a bash script?  are you writing a PHP app)

Comment: I'm talking about mongo-shell, while in MongoDB shell environment, the one provided by src/mongo/shell/mongo.js . Plain Linux terminal, no Putty, no PHP, etc.

Comment: Editing to answer that!

Comment: This is not very useful. `db.eval` already assumes connection to db. A JS script defining such command, that I could preload or import when running `$ mongo` would be useful.

Comment: I cannot stress this enough.  You.  Will.  Always.  Need.  To.  Connect.  To. A. DB. To. Run. A. Command.  What are you actually trying to do here?   If you actually just wanted the table schema from the CLI my answer solves that.  Also you said "run from the CLI" and now we're talking about JS?

If you're trying to "run any command based on JS input" perhaps you should clarify in your question.

Comment: When you say CLI, do you mean the CLI of OS or CLI of MongoDB Server?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240643/discussion-between-mindey-i-and-mason-stedman).

Comment: CLI = command line interface.  

Frankly I'm not really understanding what you're trying to do here.  You're question was how to write a 1 line command to get the table schema from the CLI.  

I assumed you meant... CLI.  do you mean you want a 1 line command to mount and select a database when you're already logged into mongo?  Or do you actually mean a 1 liner for programming purposes?

Comment: I meant CLI = mongo shell (CLI of Mongo, not of OS). From OS, yes, one could easily write a shell script or a Python script that does this, but that's not what I was after. What I was after, is less typing during navigation of databases on a MongoDB server (I found myself too many times having to enter 2 commands to do 1 thing).